# 2000 Camry does not enter programming mode

Tags: toyota, camry, fob

I've been trying to program a remote (with door lock/unlock/trunk buttons) I got off eBay for my 2000 Camry CE without much luck.

I've followed about a dozen different instructions (open door / close door / lock / unlock sequences) I found online to get the car to enter into programming mode, but none of them work.

My car does not have a chip key; and as far as I can tell it's not a valet key either (I can open my glove box with it)

Is there an official set of instructions to get the car into programming mode? Anything else I should try (other than taking it to the dealer)?

**More info:**
I'm pretty sure the fact of having a broken/wrong remote is irrelevant at this stage. The idea is that after you perform a magic "open door x 2 / close door / lock x 10 / unlock sequence" the car's locks will cycle automatically, thus letting you know you're in the programming mode; only then you'd actually program the remote.

I bought the car used, and it didn't come with the remote; is there a way to check whether the car ever had one?

Comment: Are you sure you got the right remote? Double check the numbers on old/new remote to verify. Also, is this a replacement remote, or for one you never had in the first place? Wondering if your car was ever equipped with remotes in the first place. Would be hard to program if it wasn't equipped.

Comment: I have the same problem with Toyota 2000 Camry: Does not enter the programming mode. I'm having a remote, working perfectly, then bought another one from eBay, with the same IDs and part number, for the spare. I did the procedure many time but can not get passed step #5. Did I miss something? or I have to erase the FOB memory before adding a new remote. If so, how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem programming my 2000 Camrys (two different cars!) The instructions that finally worked involved the two cycles of 5x lock/unlock using the switch on the armrest console. I had to do it probably 15 times until I finally got it right! It is important to follow the sequence exactly and wait until you hear the system click/beep indicating it is time to punch the right buttons in the right order on the remote.The following instructions worked for me when I really concentrated and got it exactly right!
Hope this helps!!!!

1 Open the driver's side door of your 2000 Toyota Camry and leave the opened door unlocked. Close and lock all other vehicle doors.

2 Insert your key into the Camry's ignition cylinder and immediately remove it. Avoid turning the ignition while inserting and removing the key from the ignition cylinder.

3 Use the power locks on the control panel of the driver's side door to cycle the vehicle through five locking cycles. Press the "Lock" button followed by the "Unlock" button. Do this five times, pressing the buttons at a steady, even pace. Quickly close and open the Camry's driver's side door.

4
Press the "Lock" and "Unlock" buttons on the driver's door control panel to take the vehicle through another five locking cycles. Quickly insert the key into the Camry's ignition cylinder and turn the ignition "On," "Off," "On," "Off." Remove the key from the vehicle's ignition cylinder.

5
Wait for the vehicle's locks to cycle on their own, indicating that you have accessed the keyless entry remote programming mode.

6
Press and hold the "Lock" and "Unlock" buttons on the keyless entry remote for at least one second. Release the "Lock" and "Unlock" buttons, then press and hold the "Lock" button for two seconds. Note that the vehicle's locks will cycle to indicate that the keyless entry remote has been successfully programmed.

7
Close the driver's side door to complete the keyless entry remote programming process for your 2000 Toyota Camry.

Read more : http://www.ehow.com/how_7266682_program-remote-2000-camry.html

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with my 2001 Camry--I had done this programming several years ago when I lost a key fob, so I knew it did work---however, when I went back to do it again, I could not get it to go into programming mode--NOTHING seemed to work.  No fuse issue or anything else I could identify.

Here is how I fixed it----the check engine light was on--I disconnected battery (both terminals) then reconnected (to clear the check engine light).  once I did that, trying the sequence then allowed the car to enter programming mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my two 2005 Toyota Camry key fobs not entering programming mode.  I tried both methods that I saw recommended, including the one mentioned here.  It turned out that the issue was a blown Dome light fuse (7.5A).  The other symptom that led me to the dome light fuse was that the clock kept resetting back to 1:00.  Anyway, I saw the following mentioned on another site and it helped me:
Check these fuses first and tell me what you find:
1- 7.5 amp DOME fuse (if the dome lamp comes on when the door opens then this is good)
2- 25amp DOOR 1 fuse
3- 10 amp ECU-B fuse
Check these fuses first...